# HasQueryFilter cannot translate query including mapped entity

Tags: entity-framework

Adding a query filter to the Tag entity to filter for a given tenant raises an error. I have provided some snippets below, which indicates most of the logic regarding the issue. The entity is mapped and the database reflects the entities correctly (with a foreign key on the Tag entity to Tenant).

DbContext

```
public string TenantName { get; } = "TenantName"
public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasQueryFilter(t => t.Tenant.Name == TenantName);
}
```

Tag

```
    public class Tag
    {
        public static string[] DefaultTags { get; } = { "Preparation" };

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsReadonly { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Tenant Tenant { get; }

        public List<DrillVideo> DrillVideos { get; set; } = new List<DrillVideo>();

        public Tag() { }
        public Tag(Tenant tenant, string value, bool isReadonly = false)
        {
            Tenant = tenant;
            Value = value;
            IsReadonly = isReadonly;
        }
```

Tenant

```
    public class Tenant
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string? WelcomeText { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(280)]
        public string? PracticalInformation { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(254)]
        public string? ContactEmail { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(35)]
        public string? ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();

        public Tenant() { }
        public Tenant(string name, string? welcomeText = null, int? id = null, string? practicalInformation = null, string? contactEmail = null, string? contactPhoneNumber = null)
            : this()
        {
            Name = name;
            if (id != null)
                Id = (int)id;
            WelcomeText = welcomeText;
            PracticalInformation = practicalInformation;
            ContactEmail = contactEmail;
            ContactPhoneNumber = contactPhoneNumber;
        }
    }
```

I Get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Tag>()
    .Where(t => t.Tenant.Name == "localhost")' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'Tenant' on entity type 'Tag' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped.
Translation of member 'Tenant' on entity type 'Tag' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at InstructrApi.Services.DrillVideoService.AddAsync(String vimeoLink, IEnumerable`1 tags) in C:\GitRepos\backend\InstructrApi\Services\DrillVideoService.cs:line 54
   at InstructrApi.Controllers.DrillVideoController.AddNewDrillVideo(AddDrillVideoDto dto) in C:\GitRepos\backend\InstructrApi\Controllers\DrillVideoController.cs:line 37
   at lambda_method135(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Host: localhost:5001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
:method: POST
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVkMzQwZGRiYzNjNWJhY2M0Y2VlMWZiOWQxNmU5ODM3ZWM2MTYzZWIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vaW5zdHJ1Y3RyLWRldiIsImF1ZCI6Imluc3RydWN0ci1kZXYiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2NjYwMDc1MjksInVzZXJfaWQiOiJOQXdsMUU5a1RNV3lFYnJJNFl3UUNoY2lxenYyIiwic3ViIjoiTkF3bDFFOWtUTVd5RWJySTRZd1FDaGNpcXp2MiIsImlhdCI6MTY2NjAxMTEyMSwiZXhwIjoxNjY2MDE0NzIxLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFkbWluQGxvY2FsLmRrIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7ImVtYWlsIjpbImFkbWluQGxvY2FsLmRrIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifX0.2wiTVyEf869sSmhLBoMYNalwMzfImCmc6_B94SdXurT7VFKDPVM3wvfDZ117MDF83CPMSUFRvGWYLQRx03ChRBhGU6oxJ8yLHrQLcDeLoknmdp_xUTDfhUI54DZ39NIVn1WBHzr63AwprvQMfJA8buN0u9mGCgPktP1vgT19iPbgmlHIaqI-gONPjI7WjW16c1Wz12wKRHWqBVLOJ0vDfGvvS4zY-KLIVXJXLORrVN8sNWAKOaM8a3g1P5qAHCBKxA3-rmNcueJ3jVev3UMefXO642AH464Nu-N6OHykyvXCGrIBJ3B7qzLrzbxdOd_HiT7ElE04GdfBJED8m8263Q
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Content-Length: 27
sec-gpc: 1
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

The entity is mapped. Why do I get the error anyways?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no setter for the Tenant property on the Tag entity.

Adding a setter to the Tenant property on the Tag entity fixed the issue.

Before:

```
public class Tag
{
    ...
    public Tenant Tenant { get; }
    ...
}
```

After

```
public class Tag
{
    ...
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    ...
}
```